# django-tinymce HTMLField covering model field description in admin/add

Tags: python, django, tinymce, django-tinymce

**The Issue**

The name of the model field is not visible in Django's admin "add" page when using [django-tinymce](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce)'s `tinymce_models.HTMLField()`. The `Name:` field is in the picture, but the `Description` field is not. How can I display the `Description` text over the TinyMCE editor?

[image]

**The Model**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    description = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
    started = models.DateField(blank=True)
```

**Versions**

- Django **1.10.4**
- django-tinymce **2.4.0**
- Tiny MCE **4.5.2**

**A Bunch of Code**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgqRqM

HTML is directly from Chrome Developer Tools on the Django admin page for adding this model. CSS is both Django's and Tiny MCE's. JS is from the Tiny MCE theme.
It doesn't seem to render correctly on Codepen so I'm not sure how useful it will be...

Let me know if there's any more clarifying information I can provide.

**More Pictures**

I know the text `Description:` is in the HTML:
[image]

This guy is covering it up?
[image]

Comment: This is really detailed lol nice job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a familiar issue. You need to move the left margin of TinyMCE 4 widget to the right. In my [django-tinymce4-lite](https://github.com/romanvm/django-tinymce4-lite) package I use the following dynamic CSS to set the widget position:

```
/* Fixes TinyMCE 4 widget position in Django admin */
.form-row .mce-tinymce {
  margin-left: {{ margin_left }}px;
}
.form-row .mce-fullscreen {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

This is the view that generates the CSS:

```
def css(request):
    """
    Custom CSS for TinyMCE 4 widget

    By default it fixes widget's position in Django Admin

    :param request: Django http request
    :type request: django.http.request.HttpRequest
    :return: Django http response with CSS file for TinyMCE 4
    :rtype: django.http.HttpResponse
    """
    if 'grappelli' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        margin_left = 0
    elif VERSION[0] == 1 and VERSION[1] <= 8:
        margin_left = 106  # For old style admin
    else:
        margin_left = 170  # For Django >= 1.9 style admin
    return render(request, 'tinymce/tinymce4.css', {'margin_left': margin_left}, content_type='text/css')
```

But if you don't support multiple Django versions, a static CSS with the necessary margin value will be enough.

Comment: I ended up using [django-tinymce4-lite](http://romanvm.github.io/django-tinymce4-lite/index.html) and it worked perfectly without me having to modify any CSS! Thank you so much!